# Shape operator and orthogonality of eigenvectors

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, curvature

When studying differential geometry (at a hobby level) I always run into problems when it comes to the varying notations and statements about the shape operator $S_p(\mathbf{x})=I^{-1}_pII_p(\mathbf{x})$. 
More specifically, my problems have to do with the orthogonality of the eigenvectors of $S_p$.

The cause of some problems might relate to uncertainty "where" (in which coordinate space) stuff is happening, so

- first of all, considering a surface $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, am I right in thinking that the parameters $\mathbf{x}$ in $S_p(\mathbf{x})$ are "from" the parameter domain, that is $\mathbf{x}\in\Omega$?

Now, let $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ be the two eigenvectors with $S_p\mathbf{u}_i=k_i\mathbf{u}_i$.
Many authors state:

*"The eigenvectors of $S_p$ are called principal directions. ...  Recall that it also follows from the Spectral Theorem that the principal directions are orthogonal..."*

- How can this be? As noted above, in my opinion $S_p$ is "evaluated" on $\Omega$. The $S_p$-Matrix is not symmetric. And hence (according to maple) $<\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2>\neq0$.

However, it seems that when speaking about orthogonality of the eigenvectors it is always implied that they are first transferred via the Jacobian $J_X$ to the tangent plane: $<J_X\mathbf{u}_1,J_X\mathbf{u}_2>=<\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2>_I=0$.
So, my intuition seems to be wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Finally, I believe prove orthogonality $<\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2>_I=0$ should be easy using simple substitutions, but I seem to be missing some linear algebraic argument... any idea?
\begin{equation}
<\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2>_I = \mathbf{u}_1^T I_p \mathbf{u}_2 = \\
\textit{using } S_p\mathbf{u}_2=I^{-1}_pII_p\mathbf{u}_2=k_2\mathbf{u}_2 \textit{ we get }\\
\frac{1}{k_2}\mathbf{u}_1^T I_p I^{-1}_pII_p\mathbf{u}_2=\frac{1}{k_2}\mathbf{u}_1^T II_p\mathbf{u}_2\\
\text{ but I cannot see how this is zero }
\end{equation}

Any pointers?

Comment: The second fundamental form is self-adjoint and, so, its matrix is symmetric. Now, every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't see it. Are you saying that because II is symmetric and its eigenvectors form an ONB, so do the eigenvectors of the shape operator S?
Or in other words what substitutions of <u_1,u_2>_I=... am I missing to make it zero?

Answer (score 4):

You make an excellent point. The matrix representation of the shape operator $S_p$ with respect to the coordinate basis may very well *not* be a symmetric matrix. [See, for example, the remark on p. 47 and Example 6 on p. 49 of [my text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).]

In your question, the vectors $\mathbf u_i$ are in the tangent plane of the surface, not back in $\Omega$. To use the first fundamental form matrix $I_p$, you would need their coordinate representations in terms of the parametrization.

Nevertheless, the shape operator, as a linear map from the tangent space of the surface to itself, is symmetric or self-adjoint. Recall that $S_p(\mathbf u) = -D_{\mathbf u}\mathbf n(p)$, where $\mathbf n$ is the Gauss mapping (i.e., unit normal of the surface) and $D_{\mathbf u}$ denotes the directional derivative (or, more fancily, the covariant derivative) in the direction of $\mathbf u$. If the coordinates in $\Omega$ are given by $u_1,u_2$ and we denote $X_i = \partial X/\partial u_i$, etc., then $X_1$ and $X_2$ give a basis for the tangent plane, and so we only need to check that $S_p(X_i)\cdot X_j = X_i\cdot S_p(X_j)$ for all $i,j=1,2$. The only nontrivial check is this:
$$S_p(X_1)\cdot X_2 = -D_{X_1}\mathbf n \cdot X_2 = -\mathbf n_1\cdot X_2 = \mathbf n\cdot X_{21} = \mathbf n\cdot X_{12} = -\mathbf n_2\cdot X_1 = S_p(X_2)\cdot X_1.$$
The two crucial ingredients here are the symmetry of second-order mixed partial derivatives and the observation that $\mathbf n\cdot X_i = 0$ implies $(\mathbf n \cdot X_i)_j = 0$.