# Why are the Eigenvalues of the shape operator the principle curvatures?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question

For now I would be content with understanding why the eigenvalues of the shape operator of a **surface** are the principle curvatures, let's call them $k_1,k_2$.

Let $f: M \rightarrow S^2$ be the Gauss map of an oriented surface $M$ into the sphere. This map simply sends the unit normal vector at any point of our surface to it's point on the sphere, I like to think of this map sort of like a trippy compass.

The differential of this map is called the **Shape Operator**.

Given a point $x \in M$, the tangent plane at $x$ is denoted $T_xM$ is an inner product space. The shape operator can be defined as a linear operator on $T_xM$ by the equation:

$$ (S_x(v),w)=(df_x(v),w) \quad \text{for any $v,w \in T_x M.$} $$

Apparently, the equation is above is symmetric in $v$ and $w$, and thus the shape operator is a self-adjoint operator. Hm... So it's symmetric in $v$ and $w$, so $(df_x(v),w)=(df_x(w),v)$? Can somebody explain to me why that makes sense??

And then yeah, if somebody could help me understand why the eigen-values of this operator are the principle curvatures, i.e. the maximum and minimum values of possible curvatures as you depart from our given point, $x$, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x}(u,v)$ be a parametrisation of $M$ around $x$, then $\{\mathbf{x}_u,\mathbf{x}_v\}$ is a basis of $T_x M$. If $N$ is the normal vector on $M$, then $df_x(\mathbf{x_u}) = N_u$ and $df_x(\mathbf{x}_v)=N_v$. Derive $(N,\mathbf{x}_u) = 0$ w.r.t $v$ and $(N, \mathbf{x}_v)=0$ w.r.t. $u$:
$$
\begin{align*}
 (N_v, \mathbf{x}_u) + (N_, \mathbf{x}_{uv}) &= 0  \\
 (N_u, \mathbf{x}_v) + (N_, \mathbf{x}_{vu}) &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
Hence
$$
   (N_u, \mathbf{x}_v) = -(N,\mathbf{x}_{uv}) = (N_v,\mathbf{x}_{u}). 
$$
By linearity, it follows that $(df_x(v),w)= (df_x(w),v)$ for all $v$, $w \in T_x M$.

For your second question, let $\mathbf{e}_1$,  $\mathbf{e}_2 \in T_x M$ be the eigenvectors of $df_x$, i.e. the principal directions, and let $k_1$, $k_2$ be the corresponding eigenvalues. Let us say that $k_1 \geq k_2$. The normal curvature $k(v)$
in a direction $v=\cos \theta\, \mathbf{e}_1+\sin \theta\, \mathbf{e}_2$ is by definition $(df_x(v),v)$. We get
$$
\begin{align*}
 k(v)= (df_x(v),v) &= (k_1 \cos \theta \,\mathbf{e}_1+ k _2 \sin \theta \,\mathbf{e}_2,\cos \theta \mathbf{e}_1+\sin \theta \mathbf{e}_2)\\
&= k_1\cos^2\theta + k_2\sin^2 \theta.
\end{align*}
$$
In some references this formula is called Eulers formula for the normal curvatures. Finally we note that.
$$
  k_1 = k_1 \cos^2\theta + k_1\sin^2\theta \geq k_1\cos^2\theta + k_2\sin^2\theta \geq k_2\cos^2\theta +k_2\sin^2\theta = k_2,
$$
so $k_1\geq k(v) \geq k_2$. This shows that the eigenvalues of $df_x$ are the maximal en minimal normal curvatures.

Comment: Awesome, thanks man!!

Comment: @Ernie060 Why can you assume that the two eigenvectors are linearly independent? In general, the shape operator matrix is not symmetric.

Comment: The shape operator matrix is always symmetric, that is what the line $(N_u, \mathbf{x}_v) = (N_v, \mathbf{x}_u)$ says. Since the shape operator is symmetric (self-adjoint), it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: @Ernie060 I am a bit confused. see the answer for that post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859884/shape-operator-and-orthogonality-of-eigenvectors, specifically, the first paragraph of the answer. It says that the shape operator matrix might not be symmetric.

Comment: Ok, that answer confuses me as well... The shape operator is a linear map from the tangent space (at a point of the surface) to that tangent space itself. Regarded as such, this map is self-adjoint, and hence it's matrix representation is symmetric. In the post you refer to, the asker apparently doesn't consider the shape operator as a map $T_x M \to T_x M$.

Comment: @Ernie060 Well, this is also puzzling me. Doesn't the shape operator allow me to calculate the differential of the Gauss map in terms of local coordinates (parametrization coordinates)?

Comment: @Ernie060 Here's another reference - https://youtu.be/e-erMrqBd1w?list=PL9_jI1bdZmz0hIrNCMQW1YmZysAiIYSSS&t=2420. If you find the difference in the formulations or definitions that lead to these discrepancies, I would be happy to know :-).

Comment: Here is my mistake: the shape operator is indeed a self-adjoint operator, but this does not imply that its matrix is symmetric. My bad. The main difference is actually explained very well in the movie and the linked question you mentioned. In the clip, the vectors $X_i$ are vectors in the _domain_ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The images $df(X_i)$ are vectors in the tangent plane. (Also, as you probably have noticed, $f$ in this question stands for the Gauss map, while in the video, it stands for a parametrisation, so comparing the different sources is painful...)

Comment: @Ernie060 Thanks for the clarification, and thanks for your time. So your proof above is correct only if we assume that the matrix representation of the shape operator is symmetric? Because otherwise, we can't assume that the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Comment: The proof is correct, without any extra assumptions. The example in the video clip illustrates the key insight. There, the vectors $X_i$ in the domain are not orthogonal on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the usual metric. But they are orthogonal w.r.t. the _induced metric_ on the domain: $\langle df(X_1),df(X_2)\rangle=0$. Note that the $df(X_i)$ are the vectors tangent to the surface. Bottom line: if you work with the vectors $X_i$ in the domain, and you want to talk about distances, angles and orthogonality, always use the induced metric or first fundamental form.