# Why are the eigen-vectors of the shape operator the principal directions of curvature?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry, soft-question

For now I would be content with understanding why the eigenvalues of the shape operator of a **surface** are the principle curvatures, let's call them $k_1,k_2$.

Let $f: M \rightarrow S^2$ be the Gauss map of an oriented surface $M$ into the sphere. This map simply sends the unit normal vector at any point of our surface to it's point on the sphere, I like to think of this map sort of like a trippy compass.

The differential of this map is called the **Shape Operator**.

Given a point $x \in M$, the tangent plane at $x$ is denoted $T_xM$ is an inner product space. The shape operator can be defined as a linear operator on $T_xM$ by the equation:

$$ (S_x(v),w)=(df_x(v),w) \quad \text{for any $v,w \in T_x M.$} $$

Could help me understand why the eigen-vectors of the shape operator are the principal directions of curvature? Thanks!!

Comment: The answer depends on what _your_ definition of principal directions is. In most references, the principal directions are defined as the eigenvector of the shape operator. If the principal directions are defined as the directions in which the normal curvature are extremal, then the answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665865/why-are-the-eigenvalues-of-the-shape-operator-the-principle-curvatures) shows that these directions are the eigenvectors of $S$.

Comment: Thanks man, your a boss. In the case when we are working on a manifold of greater than dimension two, why should one expect that the eigenvalues of the shape operator to have such a strong geometric interpretation, as the eigenvalues form a basis of some tangent space that you can use to understand the geometry of the manifold, right?

Comment: Yes, the shape operator encodes how a hypersurface is immersed in the ambient space, hence its name. And eigenvalues and eigenvectors are of course a convenient way to describe how a symmetric linear map works. More specifically, when we have a quadratic form $(S(v), v)$ with $S$ a symmetric matrix, then the maximum and minimum eigenvalues of $S$ are the maximum and minimum values of the quadratic form $(S(v),v)$. Other eigenvalues also have an interpretation (see the [min-max-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_theorem)).